# HTML text editor for webpage

Tags: html

I want arich text editor for embedding in webpage
but it should have tools and textbox seperable, i mean they should not be integrated

Comment: In All editor implementations the text box is in iframe and tools are in div or table. you can set position of toolbox and textbox with css. You can see how the dom look like in Firebug (firefox) or DragonFly (opera).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

Comment: As i said i want tools and textbox to be seperated,not the case with ckeditor or tinymce

Answer (score 1):

try
[ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

or

[tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

both are good ... but I usually use tinymce because it does not require License :)

Comment: As i said i want tools and textbox to be seperated,not the case with ckeditor or tinymce ...what i means to say is that ckeditor or tinymce places the toolbox and textbox joined together at one place,..however I want tools to be on diiferent place and its associcated textbox to be at different places on webpage