# Library for WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: javascript, content-management-system

I created a simple CMS. And now, when users add their own articles, I want them to add as html without writing any html. Just like stackoverflow does.

I use PHP and MySQL.

For example, user creates an article (user does not have html skills), now JS builds markup and this will be added into MySQL via PHP as html.

Comment: This is unclear. What are you asking here?

Comment: Stackoverflow uses markdown. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357022/what-is-a-good-client-side-markdown-editor

Comment: For example, There's WORDPRESS written in PHP. Any logged user can write/edit own article. BUT, user does not see any HTML, he just clicks on button (CENTER, LEFT, RIGHT, H2 so on). For example, when he clicks on H2, JS must automatically apply <h2> </h2> tags into selected area and

Comment: You're not asking for the *content management system*, you're asking for the editor (WordPress just happens to include an editor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow uses a Markdown system for inputting text. Specifically, [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/), which runs in the client.

It's fairly simple to use and set up, and if you want to store as HTML, you can just convert the article to HTML sometime before storing it into your MySQL database. Finding a MarkDown implementation that can be used from PHP (with sanitizer support) would probably be better than trusting the HTML generated by the article when they submit. At the very least, you should check the article to make sure it's both valid HTML and only using white-listed tags!

Answer (score 0):

There are already a number of questions just like yours: how to have a simple rich text editor or wsywig editor in a web page.

I think [this one is the most succinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870297/html-text-editor-for-webpage): try FCK Editor or TinyMCE.

Comment: Don't fuel dupes by posting answers and then explicitly saying it's a dupe. Flag it with the post it's a dupe of.

Comment: ah, oops. Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: well I never used JS before in production, so i never knew that it actually calls "WYSIWYG Editor"

Comment: now you know :) I think I've put in the TinyMCE before, and it wasn't too hard.